# Classifying human activities from accelerometer-data with neural network

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, classification, pattern-recognition

I've been tasked to carry out a benchmark of an existing classifier for my company. The biggest problem currently is differentiating between different type of transportation's, like recognizing if i'm currently in a train, driving a car or bicycling so this is the main focus.

I've been reading alot about LSTM, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short_term_memory and its recent success in handwriting and speech-recognition, where the time between significant events could be pretty long.

So, my first thought about the problem with train/bus is that there probably isn't such a clear and short cycle as there is when walking/running for instance so long-term memory is probably crucial.

Have anyone tried anything similar with decent results?
Or is there other techniques that could potentially solve this problem better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've worked on mode of transportation detection using smartphone accelerometers. The main result I've found is that almost any classifier will do; the key problem is then the set of features. (This is no different from many other machine learning problems.) My feature set ended up containing time-domain and frequency-domain values, both taken from time-series sliding-window segmentation.

Another problem is that the accelerometer can be placed anywhere. On the body, it can be anywhere and in any orientation. If the user is driving, is the phone in a pocket, in a bag, on a car seat, attached to a suction-cup window mount, etc.?

If you want to avoid these problems, use GPS instead of the accelerometer. You can make relatively accurate classifications with that sensor, but the cost is the battery usage.

Comment: With feature-set you mean the training/testing data? My data will consist of xyz forces sampled at 30hz where the current activity is known.

I wont be able to use GPS.

To avoid the orientation-problem i was thinking about using the RMS value instead, but i don't know if this is a good idea since alot of differences in the activities probably depend on what axis is affected.

Comment: You have training and testing data, but you still need to extract features from them. The process is similar to training a voice recognition system. You can use the euclidean length of the 3-d vector to eliminate orientation differences, but the result is that you cannot use orientation-based features. Some useful features are frequency sub-band energy, principal frequency, time-domain mean & stdev, time-domain zero-crossings, etc.

Comment: Ah ok now alot became clearer. But i'm not sure how i would apply it or how the extracted data would look like. Would it be overkill to train a net with the raw data?

Comment: Look in the literature for 'time series sliding window' to create windows in time, typically with some overlap of 50%. Compute features on each window; that is your feature vector. The feature vector will be labelled in your training data ('walking'), so train a model for that. I found that decision trees gave pretty good performance (> 90% accuracy) but tended to overfit; start with that before moving to a neural network.